# XML extraction from local drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fix the error but couldnt find the proper code. Someone please help

function readXML()
{

```
var xml= new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open('GET','C:\Users\ppriyadharshini\Documents\Javascript\eFORM-MAL_2022-08-26_Merlana Buenaflor_Due Date 2022-09-23_Calculation (1).xml',false);

xml.send();

varxmlData=xml.responseXML;

if(!xmlData)
{
    
    xmlData=(new DOMParser());parseFromString(xml.responseText,'text/xml');
    var req= xmlData.getElementsByTagName("my:MDRequest");
    var reqs=req[0].getElementsByTagName("my:RequestingSite")[0].firstChild.data;
    window.alert("Requesting Site:"+reqs);  
}
```

}

I got this error

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ppriyadharshini\XMLExtraction.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
at Function.Module._load
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
(node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []

Comment: You need to write the code, avoid taking picture of it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.